# How to redirectToRoute() with arguments which are not part of the route?

Tags: php, twig, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Controller with two `...Action()`-methods. When I call the route `/newTask` with the route name `newTask` inside the browser I have a form to set a `Task`-object. After submitting via `Submit`-Button I want to redirect to the route `/success` with the route name `task_success`:

```
class FormController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/newTask", name="newTask")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');

        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //Here I want to redirect...
            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success', array('task' => $task));
    }

        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/success", name="task_success")
     */
    public function successAction($task){
        return $this->render('default/success.html.twig',array('task' => $task));
    }

}
```

As you can see the method `successAction` has a parameter `$task` which I need to to show the values with the `success.html.twig`, but I don´t need `task` as a part of the route (e.g. `\success\{task}`).

So how can I redirect with the argument `$task` without using it inside the route?

Comment: `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success', array(
                    'task' => $task,
                )
));` ?

Comment: Does not work, because `Controller "AppBundle\Controller\FormController::successAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$task" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want display the task number in URL, you can pass its ID to the session flashBag before redirect and store it temporally:

```
$this->addFlash('success_task_id', $task->getId());

return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
```

Then, get this ID from session in you `successAction` method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/success", name="task_success")
 */
public function successAction(){
    $taskId = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('success_task_id');
    $task = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Task')->find($taskId);

    return $this->render('default/success.html.twig', array('task' => $task));
}
```

However, if the visibility of the task number is not important, simply use it in `newAction`:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success', array('task' => $task->getId()));
```

This generate one URL like `/success?task=1` and get the number from request query parameter bag in `successAction`:

```
public function successAction(Request $request){
    $taskId = $request->query->get('task');

    // ...
}
```

Another solution by using `serialize` and `unserialize` functions:

```
$this->addFlash('success_task', serialize($task));

return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
```

Then, get the serialized data from session in you `successAction` method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/success", name="task_success")
 */
public function successAction(){
    $task = unserialize($this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('success_task'));

    return $this->render('default/success.html.twig', array('task' => $task));
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there no way without using `ids` and `doctrine` ?

Comment: Yes, you can serialize the task object using `serialize()` and `unserialized()` functions, working with session flashBag